# regex in php on a grammar

Tags: php, regex

i'm working on a php script that is called by frontlinesms and I have set a grammar. 
the grammar would be

```
<phrase> @ <phrase> 
<phrase> = are a series of words composed of [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

and @ occurs only once, and should be between the two

i can't seem to work this out. here's my initial code:

```
preg_match_all("/(^[a-zA-Z0-9])@([a-zA-Z0-9])$/", $message_content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);

$message_content
```

contains the string

Edit: What I want to do here is to check whether the input string stored in $message_content follows the rules of the given grammar which is  @ .
I just want a return of true or false while print_r($matches) outputs Array().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
preg_match_all("/^([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)@([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)$/", $message_content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: hi! It seems it can't still check whether the string is valid based on the grammar.

Comment: What do you mean "based on the grammar"?

Comment: I mean it seems not to return whether the input is correct following the rules of the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

That regex will only match exactly one character either side of an `@`

Try

```
^([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)@([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)$
```

The `+` means one or more of the previous thing (in this instance one or more alpha-numeric or space characters)

I have included the space because you said "a series of words" (rather than "a series of word characters") if you meant the latter remove the two spaces.

Comment: hi! the output of print_r is still the same using the previous regex
it still does not check whether the pattern is correct